# Why is my GUI graphing a sorted array when running my main program, but graphs an unsorted array when running the program that creates the GUI?

Tags: swing, sorting, user-interface

I am currently working on a sorting algorithm visualizer that displays a GUI of a graph that sorts itself. This graph represents an array of random integers. I have not added the sorting functionalities to the GUI. The GUI is created in another class. The main program calls it.

The problem begins when I run the main program. When running the program that creates the GUI, the graph displays the unsorted array that it is based on. When I run my main program, the GUI displays a sorted array. I don't want the sorted array to be displayed. What could be causing this?

Main program:

```
public class sortVisualizerShell{

public static int[] unsortedArray = arrayGenerator();
public static int[] arrayGenerator() {
int N = 500;
int[] array = new int[N];
    
Random rand = new Random();
    
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int random_num = rand.nextInt(N);
    array[i] = random_num;
}
return array;
}
public static void selectionSort(int[] array, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = (i+1); j < n; j++) {
            if (array[min] > array[j]) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        int key = array[min];
        while(min > i) {
            array[min] = array[min-1];
            min = min - 1;
        }
        array[i] = key;
    }
}
public static void bubbleSort(int[] array, int n) {
    boolean swapped;
    int i,j,temp;
    for (i = 0; i < (n-1); i++) {
        swapped = false;
        for (j = 0; j < ((n-1) - 1); j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (swapped == false) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static void insertionSort(int[] array) {
    int n = array.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int key = array[i];
        int j = i -1;
        
        while (j >= 0 && array[j] > key) {
            array[j+1] = array[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        array[j+1] = key;
    }
}

public static void quickSort(int[] array, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int pivot = partition(array, left, right);
        
        quickSort(array, left, pivot - 1);
        quickSort(array, pivot + 1, right);
    }
}
public static int partition(int[] array, int low, int high) {
    int pivot = array[high];
    int i = (low - 1);
    
    for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] < pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(array, i ,j);
        }
    }
    swap(array, i + 1, high);
    return (i + 1);
}

public static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

public static void mergeSort(int[] array, int len) {
    if (len < 2) {
        return;
    }
    
    int middle = len / 2;
    
    int[] left_arr = new int[middle];
    int[] right_arr = new int[len-middle];
    
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
        if (i < middle) {
            left_arr[i] = array[i];
        }
        else {
            right_arr[k] = array[i];
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }
    
    mergeSort(left_arr, middle);
    mergeSort(right_arr, len-middle);
    
    merge(left_arr, right_arr, array, middle, (len-middle));
}



public static void merge(int[] left_arr, int[] right_arr, int[] array, int left_side, int right_side){
    int i = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    
    while (left < left_side && right < right_side) {
        if (left_arr[left] < right_arr[right]) {
            array[i++] = left_arr[left++];
        }
        else {
            array[i++] = right_arr[right++];
        }
    }
    
    while (left < left_side) {
        array[i++] = left_arr[left++];
    }
    
    while(right < right_side) {
        array[i++] = right_arr[right++];
    }

}

public static void userInputFrame(String requestedSort, int[] array) {
    
    if (requestedSort.equals("merge sort")) {   
        mergeSort(array, array.length);
    }
    else if (requestedSort.equals("quick sort")) {
        quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    }
    else if (requestedSort.equals("insertion sort")) {
        insertionSort(array);   
    }
    else if (requestedSort.equals("bubble sort")) {
        bubbleSort(array, array.length);
    }
    else if (requestedSort.equals("selection sort")) {
        selectionSort(array, array.length);
    }
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Welcome to my sort visualizer");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Which sort would you like to see in action? ");
    

    
    
    
    

    String requestedSort = myScanner.nextLine();
    requestedSort = requestedSort.toLowerCase();
    Drawer draw = new Drawer();
    draw.createGUI();
    
    
    myScanner.close();
    
    userInputFrame(requestedSort,unsortedArray);
    
    
    
    
    

}
```

}

GUI Program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Drawer extends JPanel{

    public int[] y = sortVisualizerShell.unsortedArray;

public static void createGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    Drawer draw = new Drawer();
    
    
    panel.setOpaque(false);
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,5)));
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(draw);
    frame.add(panel);
   
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(550,600);
    
   
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length;i++) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawRect(i,0, 5, y[i]);
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    };
        
        
    
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            createGUI();
        }
    });
 }

}
```

Comment: There is only one array. After sorting the array, there is only a sorted array.

Comment: I fixed it by creating a method in my main program that will sort the array when a button is activated. Nonetheless, I appreciate your comment